# How navigate views without using NavigationStack/Link?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I want to change views in my app but the only way I've found to do that natively is using NavigationStack and NavigationLink.

I have 2 issues with those:

1. The slide animation
2. The back button

I want a user to be able to click a button and be taken from one view to another. No animation, no back button in the corner.

This seems like a simple task but I've searched for hours and can't find anything.

Am I approaching this problem wrong? Should I build everything in one view and hide/show elements as they're needed? I'm wondering if I'm not supposed to build separate views for each new 'screen'.

Comment: "hide/show elements as they're needed" is not mutually exclusive with "build everything in one view". You don't have to (and should not) build everything in one view. It's rather hard to give you advice without knowing what kind of navigation you are doing? Is it sill based on a stack? Can you "go back"? Or should every navigation create a brand new view?

Comment: @Sweeper I'm looking to build an RPG game with a main screen that has 4 buttons: Fight, Skills, Inventory, and Shop. Each button should lead to a new screen that has a different UI layout. I've separated each UI layout into a different view but I'm not sure that's the right approach. 

I have the buttons working with NavigationStack/Link but I'm wondering if there are alternatives since the animation/back button aren't ideal.